# C# error CS0117 - File does not include definition for ReadAllText when I am using Google Drive API

Tags: c#

I am trying to make some client to upload files to Google Drive. I copied parts of code from some websites but I have still one error. The error has the number CS0117 and it says File does not include the definition for ReadAllText. The error is on line 55. Thank you for your answers. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using File = Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace IDK_client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Upload variables
        public bool uploadFilesSelected = false;
        public string uploadFileContent;

        //Google Drive connection variables
        static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
        static string ApplicationName = "server";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelUploadFile.Visible = false;
        }    

        private void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(uploadFilesSelected == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    OpenFileDialog openFileDialogUpload = new OpenFileDialog();
                    openFileDialogUpload.CheckFileExists = true;
                    openFileDialogUpload.CheckPathExists = true;
                    openFileDialogUpload.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\";
                    openFileDialogUpload.RestoreDirectory = true;
                    openFileDialogUpload.Title = "Select file to upload...";
                    openFileDialogUpload.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
                    openFileDialogUpload.ShowDialog();
                    labelUploadFile.Text = openFileDialogUpload.SafeFileName;
                    uploadFileContent = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialogUpload.FileName);
                    labelUploadFile.Visible = true;
                    uploadFilesSelected = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Can not open file.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }

            }

            else if(uploadFilesSelected == false)
            {
                UserCredential credential;
                credential = GetCredentials();
                // Create Drive API service.
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });
                //uploadFile();
            }

        }

        public void uploadFile(string path, DriveService service)
        {
            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
            fileMetadata.Name = Path.GetFileName(path);
            fileMetadata.MimeType = "txt";
            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "txt");
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }

            var file = request.ResponseBody;
        }

        private static UserCredential GetCredentials()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_id.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            // Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            return credential;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have a conflicting class I'm guessing.  Try `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(...`

Comment: Right.  OP is importing it as `using File = Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

likely you have something else named `File`. Fully qualify it with `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`.